# How to fix apt-get in Windows 10 docker

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm trying to get this code running in docker, it's my first time. The code isn't mine, i took it from the c++ Circle compiler website.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER Sean <circlelang@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y binutils libstdc++-10-dev wget git && \
  wget -P /home https://www.circle-lang.org/debian/build_200.tgz && \
  tar xvf /home/build_200.tgz -C /usr/bin && \
  chmod +x /usr/bin/circle && \
  git clone https://www.github.com/seanbaxter/circle /home/circle_docs
```

The code throws the following error:

```
--------------------
   3 |     MAINTAINER Sean <circlelang@gmail.com>
   4 |
   5 | >>> RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade
   6 |
   7 |     RUN apt-get update && \
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Comment: You usually rely on the Docker image to be up to date, so normally you don't run `apt-get upgrade` at all. You also run `apt-get update` twice. Try deleting line 5 in the Dockerfile and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error on line 5, simply move `-y` to the update command:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
```

However, as mentioned by Hans Kilian earlier, this line may not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Now the error now is another one though. Here it is: `ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&   apt-get install -y binutils libstdc++-10-dev wget git &&   wget -P /home https://www.circle-lang.org/debian/build_200.tgz &&   tar xvf /home/build_200.tgz -C /usr/bin &&   chmod +x /usr/bin/circle &&   git clone https://www.github.com/seanbaxter/circle /home/circle_docs" did not complete successfully: exit code: 8`